# Apache poi generate file with exception

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I used the XSSFWorkbook class to generate an excel file `Workbook book = new XSSFWorkbook()`

To optimize the application, I decided to switch to SXSSFWorkbook `SXSSFWorkbook book = new SXSSFWorkbook()`

As it turns out, the `SXSSFSheet`  that provides `SXSSFWorkbook`  does not have a `createTable(AreaReference)` method, so I used the following:
`XSSFTable table = ((SXSSFWorkbook) book).getXSSFWorkbook().getSheetAt(0).createTable(reference);`

And now, when generating a file, I get errors, despite the fact that i can interact with the file itself and the table:
`Repaired Records: Table from /xl/tables/table1.xml part (Table)`

If i replace `SXSSFWorkbook` with `XSSFWorkbook` and the table creation method with `XSSFTable table = ((XSSFSheet) sheet).createTable(reference);`, then there are no errors

This is what the method itself looks like:

```
     public static void createTable(Workbook book,
                                    sheet sheet,
                                    stringname,
                                    int pRowStart,
                                    int pColStart,
                                    int pRowEnd,
                                    int pColEnd) {
         AreaReference reference = book.getCreationHelper().createAreaReference(
                 new CellReference(pRowStart, pColStart), new CellReference(pRowEnd, pColEnd)
         );
         XSSFTable table = ((SXSSFWorkbook) book).getXSSFWorkbook().getSheetAt(0).createTable(reference);
// XSSFTable table = ((XSSFSheet) sheet).createTable(reference);
         if (table.getArea() != null) {
             table.getCTTable().addNewAutoFilter().setRef(table.getArea().formatAsString());
         }
     }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75164355/get-smart-excel-table-with-apache-poi/75172222#75172222